# Crawling Google Search with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-api, web-crawler

I trying to get my head around how to fetch Google search results with PHP or JavaScript. I know it has been possible before but now I can't find a way.

I am trying to duplicate (somewhat) the functionality of
 http://www.getupdated.se/sokmotoroptimering/seo-verktyg/kolla-ranking/

But really the core issue I want to solve is just to get the search result via PHP or JavaScript,the rest i can figure out.

Fetching the results using file_get_contents() or cURL doesn't seem to work.

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.se/#hl=sv&q=dogs');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Results:

> string(219) "302 Moved The document has moved here."

So, with some Googling i found http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html but that seems to only work for generating a custom search for one or more websites.
It seem to require a "Custom Search Engine" cx-parameter passed.

So anyway, any idea?

Comment: You will need `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` flag set to true

Comment: @zerkms Any other suggestions? Is there any legal ways? I really want to do this in a legal way, but I haven't found one. That was part of my question.

Comment: @jamietelin: the first result in google by request "google search API" https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/ Don't be so lazy

Comment: @zerkms I am not lazy, I have read that, from start to finish + the customs search api. But you haven't, obviously :) `Note: The Google Web Search API has been officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day will be limited. Therefore, we encourage you to move to the new Custom Search API.`

Comment: @jamietelin: I actually have read it. I know it is deprecated, now you know it as well. It's deprecated, so there is no legal way of doing that. So obviously you're making your assumptions about whether I read it or not with huge lack of info.

Comment: @zerkms Where are you trying to get with this? Are you winning?

Comment: @jamietelin: I'm trying to tell that you're doing illegal thing. And be prepared to be banned by google.

Comment: @zerkms Who says I am doing anything? I am asking. And since the one legal way I knew about is depricated, I asked. Simple. But anyway, let's just leave it at that.

Comment: ...and also how is http://www.getupdated.se/sokmotoroptimering/seo-verktyg/kolla-ranking/ + all others do it if there is no legal way?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it earlier. Generate the html contents by making `https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&output=search&q=india` http request, now parse specific tags using the htmldom php library. You can parse the content of result page using [PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

> **DEMO : Below code will give you title of all the result :**

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&output=search&q=india');

$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('li[class=g]') as $element) {
    foreach($element->find('h3[class=r]') as $h3) 
    {
        $title[$i] = '<h1>'.$h3->plaintext.'</h1>' ;
    }
       $i++;
}
print_r($title);

?>
```

Comment: @JakeGould : I know. I gave another solution to jamietelin so that he can get alternate fast way to solve his problem.

Comment: Problem was the url it seems. It works with CURL as well now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is php [a github package named google-url](https://github.com/SneakyBobito/google-url) that does the job.

The api is very comfortable to use. See the example :

```
// this line creates a new crawler
$googleUrl=new \GoogleURL\GoogleUrl();
$googleUrl->setLang('en'); // say for which lang you want to search (it could have been "fr" instead)
$googleUrl->setNumberResults(10); // how many results you want to check
// launch the search for a specific keyword
$results = $googleUrl->search("google crawler");
// finaly you can loop on the results (an example is also available on the github page)
```

However you will have to think to use a delay between each query, or else google will consider you as a bot and ask you for a captcha that will lock the script.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Because if I do a `curl` from the command like I get a `200 OK`:

```
curl -I 'http://www.google.se/#hl=sv&q=dogs'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 20:45:02 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=b82cb66e9d996c48:FF=0:TM=1359319502:LM=1359319502:S=D-LW-_w8GlMfw-lX; expires=Tue, 27-Jan-2015 20:45:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.se
Set-Cookie: NID=67=XtW2l43TDBuOaOnhWkQ-AeRbpZOiA-UYEcs7BIgfGs41FkHlEegssgllBRmfhgQDwubG3JB0s5691OLHpNmLSNmJrKHKGZuwxCJYv1qnaBPtzitRECdLAIL0oQ0DSkrx; expires=Mon, 29-Jul-2013 20:45:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.se; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Also, maybe consider setting a `urlencode` for the passed URL so this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.se/#hl=sv&q=dogs');
```

Changes to this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.se/' . urlencode('#hl=sv&q=dogs'));
```

Comment: You dont want to urlencode the whole url :) The problem is most likely that he has not the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION flag set.