# Script to search and copy the definition of all entries of my data file from google

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, excel

In my Microsoft excel data file, I have a list of nearly 15,000 entries of various words and technical terms. I need all of their definitions or explanations. Is there any way to scrap the definition for each of the word/term from google and and save them to their corresponding column? In case no available definition, then the snippet of the first search result?

Is that possible to do it with any script, so that I won't have to search through all those 15,000 entries one by one. Like the example image below-
[image: Example]

It is not compulsory to stick to excel. I'm open to any other possible solution to achieve this same outcome. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552043/crawling-google-search-with-php) might give you an idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, yes, this is possible.

The somewhat longer answer is that Google actively tries to stop such scraping with Captchas and other anti-scraping tactics, so simplistic solutions like doing 15,000 calls to Google are unlikely to be much faster than doing it manually.

Fortunately, there's a free library designed to deal with this. You can find it at http://scraping.compunect.com/.

(For the record, I have no affiliation with the library's author.)